# Flutter setstate() doesn't work with sleep()

Tags: flutter, async-await, setstate

I have a simple problem but I'm new to Flutter. I have to change the colors of 3 buttons, then wait 2 seconds and call another function.
This is the Code:

```
setState((){
   clr[0]= 0==gst ? Colors.green:Colors.red;
   clr[1]= 1==gst ? Colors.green:Colors.red;
   clr[2]= 2==gst ? Colors.green:Colors.red;
 });

 sleep(const Duration(seconds:2));

 cardKey.currentState.toggleCard(); // second function
```

The problem is that this code waits 2 seconds then change the colors and call the second function...

I tried also with the `sleep()` inside the `setstate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `Future.delayed` to solve your issues as `sleep` is not recommended. Make sure to define your function as `async`. However, if you don't want to mark as async (or the function doesn't work with async), you can use this:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((_) {
  cardKey.currentState.toggleCard(); // second function
});
```

For more reading, I recommend [this](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/dart-future-duration-delay-example).